# Set SLA for Oozie job in WAITING status

Tags: oozie, hue, oozie-workflow

I have a Coordinator, which has a data dependency on a parquet directory, partitioned by date. And it runs every day in the morning. If the file isn't available for that day, the workflow goes into "WAITING" status.

Now I want to use the Oozie SLA feature to alert for this condition. Unfortunately I am not able to get this setup following the standard Oozie SLA feature. This feature is working, if my jobs is in "RUNNING" status, but takes too long to complete, but n**ot if the workflow is in "WAITING"** status. Oozie documentation doesn't have any references to this, so appreciate any advice on how to set it up.

https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/DG_SLAMonitoring.html

Comment: anybody has any idea?